# Global variable not recognised in Geolocation method - JavaScript

Tags: javascript, jquery, geolocation, global-variables

The code section below makes use of the Geolocation.getCurrentPosition() method to determine the geographic location of the web user, save it to a globally initialized variable and then write it to the display. The global variables are then to be used later on in the script for another calculation but, when this is attempted the new values of the variables are not recognized and the result is left undefined.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  var lat;
  var long;

  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(success);

  function success(position) {
    lat = position.coords.latitude;
    long = position.coords.longitude;
    $('#geoLocInFunc').text(lat + ',' + long);
  };

  $('#geoLocOutFunc').text(lat + ',' + long);

})
```

I'm sure there's a different way to get the same result but, I need to know if I'm misunderstanding something related to functions, methods or global variables.

Comment: `getCurrentPosition` is asynchronous, you print `lat` before `success` has been invoked and the variables populated.

Comment: What could I do to have success invoke before the "$('#geoLocOutFunc').text(lat + ',' + long);" line executes?

Comment: Well you don't need to, do it inside `success()` or call a function from there that does it

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your success function will only get called once the browser has determined the geolocation. It does not get called immediately. Therefore this statement after the success function definition:

```
$('#geoLocOutFunc').text(lat + ',' + long);
```

is called before success is executed.

The best way to understand what is happening is to add alert statements at appropriate places.